# Parse arbitrary length date String with DateTimeFormatter

Tags: date, java-8

I am attempting to parse a date string of (almost) arbitrary length. The approach I had with SimpleDateFormat was something like this

```
private Date parseWithSimpleDateFormat(String dateString) throws ParseException {
    String pattern = "yyyyMMddHHmmss".substring(0, dateString.length());
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    return format.parse(dateString);
}
```

... which I want to do "better" with the new Date API. What I've come up with is the following

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter FLEXIBLE_FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("yyyy[MM[dd[HH[mm[ss]]]]]")
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 1)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0)
    .toFormatter();

private Date parseWithDateTimeFormatter(String dateString) {
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString, FLEXIBLE_FORMATTER);
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    Instant instant = zonedDateTime.toInstant();
    return Date.from(instant);
}
```

with the following outcome

```
parseWithDateTimeFormatter("2016"); // works as intended
parseWithDateTimeFormatter("201605"); // Text '201605' could not be parsed at index 0
parseWithDateTimeFormatter("20160504"); // Text '20160504' could not be parsed at index 0
parseWithDateTimeFormatter("2016050416"); // Text '2016050416' could not be parsed at index 0
parseWithDateTimeFormatter("201605041636"); // Text '201605041636' could not be parsed at index 0
```

What am I doing wrong here, or how would I further troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this modified formatter in order to avoid parsing more than 4 digits for the year:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter FLEXIBLE_FORMATTER =
    new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR, 4)
    .appendPattern("[MM[dd[HH[mm[ss]]]]]")
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 1)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0)
    .toFormatter();
```

In contrast to other fields like month (MM) etc., the year field symbol y has no limitation to four digits as indicated by count of y-letters.

Comment: Thanks, this should solve my problem. Do you happen to have a reference at hand? Is this part of the API documentation, that I overlooked?

Comment: @PatrickPeer If you (very) carefully compare the sections for parsing general number versus years in [API-doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) then you can at least suspect something odd about the behaviour when 4 or more symbols are given. However, the javadoc is really not sufficient here. And you could also look at [CLDR-spec](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) which has more details. JSR-310-formatting follows in many aspects CLDR (although NOT 1:1).